# pyspark FPGrowth doesn't work with RDD

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to use the FPGrowth function on some data in Spark. I tested the example here with no problems:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-frequent-pattern-mining.html

However, my dataset is coming from hive

```
data = hiveContext.sql('select transactionid, itemid from transactions')
model = FPGrowth.train(data, minSupport=0.1, numPartitions=100)
```

This failed with Method does not exist:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o764.trainFPGrowthModel. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method trainFPGrowthModel([class org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame, class java.lang.Double, class java.lang.Integer]) does not exist
```

So, I converted it to an RDD:

```
data=data.rdd
```

Now I start getting some strange pickle serializer errors.

```
net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for pyspark.sql.types._create_row)
```

Then I start looking at the types. In the example, the data is run through a flatmap. This returns a different type than the RDD.

RDD Type returned by flatmap: pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD

RDD Type returned by hiveContext: pyspark.rdd.RDD

FPGrowth only seems to work with the PipelinedRDD. Is there some way I can convert a regular RDD to a PipelinedRDD?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, my query was wrong, but changed that to use collect_set and then
I managed to get around the type error by doing:

```
data=data.map(lambda row: row[0])
```